# Авторизация на удаленном компьютере

Tags: авторизация, клиент-сервер

Есть следующее решение - написан простой сервер, который только слушает определенный порт. Есть клиент, который подключается к порту.
На этом этапе все хорошо, подключение происходит. Далее, клиент должен пройтись по системному диску, ища файлы по указанной в форме клиента маске.
И тут проблема - у клиента нет прав на некоторые системные папки (типа "Documents and Settings"). Как я могу передать с клиента пару логин/пароль? Или же можно модифицировать сервер, чтобы он работал с правами администратора?

Comment: А с какимми правами он работает сейчас?

Comment: Сервер запускается под текущим пользователем. В отладке при запуске клиента получаю это An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Documents and Settings".